# update multiple worksheets from a module with an absolute cell reference?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm in a module function, and I have a value that needs to get updated across multiple worksheets.  I would like to take a data driven approach to this, since it may change a bit in the future.

In essence, I want to create an array of strings, each entry is an absolute reference to a cell, something like so:

```
Array("'Sheet1'!$A$1","'Sheet2'!$C$5")
```

I'd like to be able to do something like so

```
for each item in arr
  Range(item).value = some_value
next item
```

The issue is that I'm in a module, The Range property is only available on a worksheet, and if I try to reference worksheet B from worksheet A via the Range property, it gives me an error.

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of range objects like so:

```
arr = Array(WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), WorkSheets("Sheet2").Range("C5"))

Dim rng as Range

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
  arr(i).Value = some_value
Next i
```

You could also use the Collection class

```
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim rng As Range

coll.Add WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
coll.Add WorkSheets("Sheet2").Range("C5")

For Each rng In coll
  rng.Value = some_value
Next rng
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of string addresses, you can process it like

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim sh As String, addr As String
    Dim item As Variant

    arr = Array("'Sheet 1'!$A$1", "'Sheet2'!$C$5")

    For Each item In arr
        sh = Replace(Left(item, InStr(item, "!") - 1), "'", "")
        addr = Mid(item, InStr(item, "!") + 1)
        Worksheets(sh).Range(addr) = some_value
    Next
End Sub
```

If you can switch to an array (or collection) of `Range` then justnS' answer is better.  But if you need to stick with an array of strings, this will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You ask about multiple worksheets but say your program may be extended later.  If it possible that you will need to update multiple workbooks, the following may be helpful.

I have set the array elements to workbook name, worksheet name, cell address and value.  I have assumed the destination workbooks are open although it would not be difficult for the macro to open them if necessary.  I test the workbook and worksheet names but not the cell address.

```
Sub Test1()
'
 Dim Dest() As Variant
 Dim DestPart() As String
 Dim Found As Boolean
 Dim InxBook As Integer
 Dim InxDest As Integer
 Dim InxSheet As Integer

  Dest = Array("Test1.xls|Sheet3|B1|abc", "Test2.xls|Sheet2|F5|def", _
               "Test3.xls|Sheet1|D3|ghi")
    ' Each element of Dest contains: workbook name, sheet name, cell address,
    ' and value separated by pipes.

  ' This code assumes the destination workbooks are already open.

  For InxDest = LBound(Dest) To UBound(Dest)
    DestPart = Split(Dest(InxDest), "|")
    Found = False
    For InxBook = 1 To Workbooks.Count
      If DestPart(0) = Workbooks(InxBook).Name Then
        Found = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    If Found Then
      With Workbooks(InxBook)
        Found = False
        For InxSheet = 1 To .Sheets.Count
          If DestPart(1) = .Sheets(InxSheet).Name Then
            Found = True
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If Found Then
          .Sheets(InxSheet).Range(DestPart(2)).Value = DestPart(3)
        End If
      End With
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```